# Symfony2 app.session."flash" usage and cleaning

Tags: php, symfony, session-variables, symfony-2.1

I am using Symfony2 flash messages in my forms to build different views after form submit. 
So far everything is as expected, but now I want that the session.flash message (just in one form) do not still alive once this form response view has been rendered.

```
{% if app.session.hasFlash('something') %}
   ...some code...
{% endif %}
```

I have researched about that, but apart the [official reference](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session.html#method_removeFlash) with functions to delete this flash, I have not found any information.

**Someone knows which one is the best practice to do that?** Remove this flash in some particular place (p.e. a controller or event) or maybe exists some option to limit the flash message lifetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are just checking this, but not calling - flash still will be housed in session. To trigger session removing - you have to call `getFlash()` on it.

Currently, the difference between calling [`getFlash()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.php#L298) and [`removeFlash()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.php#L333) is only in fact that first method returns value.

For your particular case I recommend you to call getFlash() with second argument, which determines default return value in case if requested index does not exist.

```
{% if app.session.getFlash('something', false) %}
   ...some code...
{% endif %}
```